# Low Variables & Grid with text input containing http:// gives 403 error on save

Tags: error, low-variables, grid

EE 2.7.2
LV 2.4.0

I have low variables variable containing a grid with two text inputs and a radio button. In the text input for a link, if I add a link containing http:// and save I get taken to a 403 error. If I save the link without http:// everything saves just fine.

Any idea how to fix this? Is it a bug? if so with Grid or with Low Variables?

In case it's relevant have included a screenshot of my grid settings.
[image]

Comment: Is this happening for all URLs or just a specific one? Does http://domain.com work?

Answer (score 2):

I would check to see if you have mod_security installed on your server. That seeing the `http://` in your form post (saving LV) may be triggering the save to be blocked.

Comment: Jeremy, went to php_info and did a search for mod_security and it returned nothing.

Comment: Actually, this most likely *is* mod_security. The 403 will be thrown before it even hits PHP, so this is out of LV's, Grid's or EE's hands. Check with your host if it's enabled and if they can make an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try with a blank htaccess file. Could be an error in your .htaccess rules.